# Why Automatic Time doesn't work

Tags: time, clock

Recently I realized the automatic time doesn't work.

I guess the battery that keeps the time in my computer is bad, so I need the system to take the right time from Internet.

I'm testing changing the year and it is not automatically fixed. I'm using Compiz. 
[image]

I'm pretty sure the problem is caused by Dual Boot (Windows/Ubuntu).

But in this moment I'm telling Ubuntu to take the time from Internet.

Why it doesn't work?

I think this must have a fix inside Ubuntu regardless of the dual boot.

Comment: Is it off by a consistent amount? If so see previous comment. Or does it drift?

Comment: [Joe P](https://askubuntu.com/users/25383/joe-p): Half an hour difference. Probaby related to recently installed Windows 8 (dual booting). I already fixed it, but I still have the doubt: Why Automatic Time doesn't work?

Comment: A fixed difference means Automatic Time **is** working, but your two OSes don't agree about understanding time zones. Have you read the "Clock time is off" answers?

Comment: [Joe P](https://askubuntu.com/users/25383/joe-p): Yes, I have read the "Clock time is off" answers. Then I changed Ubuntu to "local time". Now the two OSes uses the same time. But the automatic time seems not be working: If I manually change the time and then switch to automatic, the system doesn't fix the time. This bring us, again, to my question, ***which is not duplicated*** :  Why Automatic Time doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In KDE (Kubuntu), `System Settings` > `Date & Time` > check `Set date and time automatically`. You may want to adjust the NTP server to your region.

In Unity / Gnome the settings will be something similar.

Comment: Please see this [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4gb2dfdpIGeNVBybUJ3akZVd2c). I'm testing changing the year and it is not automatically fixed. I'm using Compiz.

Comment: As I asked on the original question, is it off by a consistent amount? Or does it drift? It's still not clear whether you have a problem with not getting ntp time or with having the wrong time-zone offset (which the question linked as a duplicate will fully answer).

Comment: [Joe P](https://askubuntu.com/users/25383/joe-p): Half an hour difference. Probaby related to recently installed Windows 8 (dual booting). I already fixed it, but I still have the doubt: Why Automatic Time doesn't work?